# Windows 10 user is acting up

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, minecraft, windows-store

My Windows (not necessarily Microsoft) account has been malfunctioning lately. It takes some seconds for the internet to activate, and various Microsoft-related apps (such as the Microsoft Store and the Xbox app) either do not log in or don't load.
I contacted Microsoft support and they said that my account (They didn't specify if it was a Windows or Microsoft account) was corrupted. I moved all my files and whatnot to a new Windows account, and everything functioned for a few days, then broke.
Minecraft Bedrock gives an error code of "Cauldron" and the Microsoft Store gives an error code of 0x80131500.
Does anyone have any advice on what to do?

Thanks.

Comment: 0x80131500 can have different causes. It's often suggested to clean the Microsoft Store's cache: Press Windows+R, type `WSReset.exe` and enter. Reboot when finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Windows 10 user is acting up

You post very strongly suggests repeated USER Profile Damage. One user gone bad, new user went bad after a week.

Windows Repair Install (Keep Everything, Keep just Data) will NOT fix user profile damage.

Review what is installed and what might be causing issues. Something installed or something that you may have done is causing the profile damage.

Run Windows Defender (Full Scan and then Offline Scan) to check for viruses.

Now (because of the Profile damage), back everything up, and use Windows Reset - Keep Nothing to reinstall Windows.

Install software slowly, known good apps first. Recover data and then test for a day or two with limited software installed.

That will help you back to a working system.

Comment: Wow, that was quick. I'll try this, thanks.

Comment: This was the solution. The problematic app was a modded install of Kerbal Space Program, which I've relocated to its own user.